# Defaultdict, group by key

Tags: python

I have a default dict with keys/values like the following:

```
(foo, bar) : 1
(foo2, bar2) : 2
(foo, bar3) : 3
(foo, bar8) : 5
(foo2, bar9) : 6
```

What's the best way to aggregate the keys? i.e. get something like:

```
foo : {bar : 1, bar3 : 3, bar8 : 5}
foo2 : {bar2 : 2, bar9 : 6}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way it to construct a new `defaultdict`. Assuming `dd` is your initial dict:

```
aggregated = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for (key1, key2), val in dd.items():
    aggregated[key1][key2] = val
```